# Add html code into ModelAndView as attribute

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring

Normally if I have to add some html code dynamically, I would like to load from the view with JQuery, and then I render a ModelAndView from the controller using @ResponseBody, since I believe that adding static html from Javascript is not readable and is not reusable. 
Now I have a case where making a Ajax call I need to check some values from the controller and then render back a map with some values, or render an html code to be added into the DOM. So I have been thinking about how the ModelAndView works, and how can I add a view to be processed on the viewManagement, but only being render if I decide to append that data.
So imagine that I would like to have a map with this values

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>
    map.add("status", "1")
```

And in another scenario

```
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>
        map.add("status", "2")
        map.add("rowErros", "WEB-INF/row_errors.jsp")
```

And then in the view

```
      success:function(data)
             if(data.status=="2") $("#rowErrorsTable tbody tr:last").after(data.rowErros);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't happen to agree that including markup in client-side code is per se less readable or reusable, but regardless, I'm not sure why you would choose to use a ModelAndView for this use case. You could accomplish this on the frontend using success and error callbacks, and by returning appropriate HTTP response codes from your controller method:

```java
@Request(value="/foo")
public ResponseEntity<String> foo() {
    if (conditionIsMet()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("", HttpStatus.OK); // Or some simple JSON string
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

And on the frontend:

```js
success: doSuccess,
error: function() { $('#error').load('/error.jsp'); } // Optionally sniff for the incoming status code
```

Assuming your error case is far less frequent than your success case, then you're also:

1. saving your users the bandwidth associated with transmitting the markup of `error.jsp` with each payload;
2. using HTTP status codes as appropriate responses to HTTP requests, which cleans up and normalizes your API

If you need additional information in your error payload, consider a JSON object that gives the frontend information about the error over and above what the HTTP status code itself provides. That's not necessary in many cases, but it can be useful for `BAD_REQUEST` situations where you wish to surface what incoming request element caused the request to fail.

Comment: No, no you dont understand. I´m not sending the html code in all scenarios. Only if there´s an error, in one case and then I have to send back a list of rows to be added into an error table. And precisely I dont want redirect because is when I´m trying to save the info, when I know how many rows cannot be inserted, and then send them back into the view to be added into the DOM. If I have to redirect to check those errors rows again would be repeat the action again, so I think that would be very inefficient.